# Implement Tree-structure computation graph in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I would like to implement [TreeLSTM](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/treelstm) in Theano run on tree-structure dataset (like [Sentiment Treebank](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html)). However, I have trouble implement the tree structure.

I have done a simple example of the tree-structure computation graph. Given the binary tree, each node has its value. For each node, I would like to calculate h = child_h_1 + child_h_2 + val.

Here is the illustration of a computation graph of a unit.
[image: unit]

```
class ChildSumModule():
    """
    Sum value of two child and its value
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = theano.shared(1,name='W')

    def get_recursive_module(self, child_h):
        # internal_h = node val + h of children
        cur_val = T.lscalar('val')
        child_h_sum = T.sum(child_h, axis=0)
        h = T.dot(child_h_sum, self.W) + cur_val
        return (cur_val, h)

    def get_leaf_module(self):
        # for leaf node (without any children)
        # leaf h = its val
        cur_val = T.lscalar('val')
        h =  cur_val
        return (cur_val, h)
```

Then, I connect the unit to each other by traversal child_node-> cur_node. For leaf node, I use **get_leaf_module**, for internal node, I use **get_recursive_module** 
Then I put *val* into input list, *h* into output list to build Theano function.

```
def _build_graph(self,tree):
    """
    Build computation graph
    traversal in left, right, cur_node
    :param tree: root node of the tree
    :return: (input_val, output_h)
    """
    list_val = [] # input of computation graph
    list_h = [] # output of computation graph
    def build_cell(node, children_h):
        if (node.has_child()):
            assert len(children_h) > 0
            val, h = self.builder.get_recursive_module(children_h)
        else:
            val, h = self.builder.get_leaf_module()
        return val, h

    def recursive_build_graph(node):
        if(node.has_child()):
            h_1 = recursive_build_graph(node.children[0])
            h_2 = recursive_build_graph(node.children[1])
            input_val, h = build_cell(node, [h_1, h_2])
        else:
            input_val, h = build_cell(node, None)
        list_val.append(input_val)
        list_h.append(h)
        return h

    recursive_build_graph(tree)
    return list_val, list_h

def _traversal_tree(self, tree):
    """
    :param tree: root node
    :return: list of value of each node, traversal left, right, cur_node
    """
    list_val = []
    def traversal_recursive(tree):
        if (tree.has_child()):
            traversal_recursive(tree.children[0])
            traversal_recursive(tree.children[1])
            val = tree.val
            list_val.append(val)
        else:
            list_val.append(tree.val)

    traversal_recursive(tree)
    return list_val
```

This is how I compute h for the whole tree.

```
   def compute_tree(self, tree):
        """
        Compute h for whole tree.
        Traversal left, right, cur_node
        :param tree: root node
        :return: a list of h for each node
        """
        g_list_val, g_list_h = self._build_graph(tree) # return theano variable of each node
        list_val = self._traversal_tree(tree) #
        f = theano.function(g_list_val, g_list_h, allow_input_downcast=True)
        result = f(*list_val)
        return result
```

How the tree look like: 
(numbers in circle are val)
(number outside circle are h we need to find)
[image: tree]

I would like to ask if this is good approach for tree structure computation graph.

My code on Github:  https://github.com/ttpro1995/ChildSumTree

Comment: What is Theano?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Theano is a deep learning framework on Python (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/)